# How to get search to display an error when no search terms are entered

Tags: 7, search

Right now if I don't enter a search query in the drupal search module, it returns results for 'search'. I would like it to display an error prompting the user to enter a search query instead. Is there some sort of setting?

Comment: If the search term doesn't contain at least three characters, the Search module should already report an error message.

Comment: but if i don't enter anything it searches for search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form submission callback for the search form is the following function.

```
function search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $keys = $form_state['values']['processed_keys'];
  if ($keys == '') {
    form_set_error('keys', t('Please enter some keywords.'));
    // Fall through to the drupal_goto() call.
  }

  $type = $form_state['values']['module'] ? $form_state['values']['module'] : 'node';
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'search/' . $type . '/' . $keys;
  return;
}
```

If, when you don't enter anything, Drupal searches for *search*, there must be a module that alter the content of `$form_state['values']['processed_keys']` when it is an empty string.

Comment: I don't think so.. could it possibly be the theme?

Comment: @Ima Student Themes are not supposed to change the search string, and a theme doesn't usually implement `hook_form_alter()`.

Comment: I found it. It was actually in one of the include files in my theme `// Set a default value for the search box
  $vars['form']['search_theme_form']['#value'] = t('Search...');`
thanks for helping me get started on where to look though!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's lazy, but I would do it with javascript.  You'd save the extra wait time, and the load on your site.